# In AngularJS, how does $scope.someFunction get triggered when the model change?

Tags: angularjs

I think I can understand AngularJS's 2-way binding: `$scope.foo` observes on `<input type="text" ng-model="foo">` and the `<input>` or `{{ foo }}` observe on `$scope.foo` as well.

But what about functions that uses `$scope.foo` and functions that are used in `{{ bar() }}` -- what is the principle of who is observing who?

---

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rt07o7sL/

```
<p>{{ pigLatin() }}</p>

<input type="text" ng-model="s" style="width: 600px">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.s = "type some more here";
$scope.pigLatin = function() {
    return $scope.s + " ey ey";
}
```

Here, when the input box content is changed (by the user typing), `$scope.s` will get changed and somehow it triggered `pigLatin()`.

Answer (score 2):

`{{}}` expressions will be evaluated every `$digest` cycle, so every time something changes Angular will check every `{{}}` and `ng-bind` on the page, so when you do `{{ pigLatin() }}` and you type in the `input` a `$digest` is triggered and your function will be executed again.

More info about the `$digest` cycle [here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/).

Comment: For the same reason we should not use many {{}}. This will make slow our application.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple actually.

When you have `{{ pigLatin() }}` in the view, angular creates a "watcher" on that expression, and the responsibility of this watcher is to change the DOM (i.e. the text in the HTML page) when the expression value changes.

When you type something in the input, an angular event listener is called. The listener updates the `s` attribute of the scope, and calls `$scope.$apply()`.

This evaluates all the watched expressions, including the expression `"pigLatin()"`. Evaluating that expression consists in calling the function `pigLatin()`. If the value returned by the function is different from the last one, the watcher of that expression is called, and it updates the DOM.

This is explained in [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).